# Maintaining Single Variable[APP_MODE] for Different Activity stacks in a single application

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, activity-stack, launchmode

I am working on an application where i have 3 launcher Splash Activities and as soon as its gets installed, its shows three launcher icons(for three activities).

Now since each activity starts on  a different Activity stack and the rest Code is common for all three stacks i need a variable to differentiate from which stack the Activity was started . on the basis of that i will load the data.

Also in case of push notifications if multiple stacks are already in background, how to launch the activity in a specific stack.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#Affinities

Comment: post your manifest please. This is difficult to understand without it.